# Partitioning a list by cumulated sum when the accumulate reaches a fixed value

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list `dat = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 40}` .

When the cumulative sum of `dat` reaches `>=` 25,  the cumulative sum is halted, the difference between 25 and the cumulative sum until that point will be added to the next element of `dat` and the cumulative sum restarts until  hit 25 again and so on.

The desired result should be `{{10, 20, 25}, { 15, 25}, {25}, {15}}`

I can´t figure out how to accomplish this task, either procedural or functional

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a procedural solution:

```
acc = 0;
rem = 0;
list = {};
sublist = {};
Do[
  acc += el + rem;
  rem = 0;
  If[
   acc >= 25,
   AppendTo[sublist, 25];
   AppendTo[list, sublist];
   sublist = {};
   rem = Mod[acc, 25];
   acc = 0;
   ,
   AppendTo[sublist, acc]
   ]
  , {el, dat}];
If[rem > 0, AppendTo[list, {rem}]];

list
```

> `{{10, 20, 25}, {15, 25}, {25}, {15}}`

Comment: It works!!! With a list of Length=100.000 , Average value 133000 and Partitioning when the Cumulative Sum reaches 1200000 , the Absolute Timing was 0.37. Thank´s for your time